# i think orchard cms V1.10.3 commands changed in compare with the last orchard versions commands. that's right?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I use Orchard CMS version 1.10.3 . i want create one custom html based on TheThemeMachine theme .
in all tutorials say command for create theme is :

```
codegen theme MyFirstTheme/BasedOn:TheThemeMachine
```

but this not work for me .

i use help command for theme in command prompt . give me 2 commands. 
activate and list .

i think commands changed in compare with last versions. that's right ?

all tutorials about Orchard CMS is for Last Versions and is old !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

how to learn new commands about orchard cms ?

some tutorials remove codegen from first of command and :

```
theme MyFirstTheme/BasedOn:TheThemeMachine
```

i try this code :

```
theme MyFirstTheme/BasedOn:TheThemeMachine
```

after enter this code , show error and not work .

---

my error :

```html
Error executing command "theme MyFirstTheme/BasedOn:TheThemeMachine"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

No command found matching arguments "theme MyFirstTheme/BasedOn:TheThemeMachine". Commands available: help commands,help,cultures list,cultures get site culture,cultures set site culture,cultures add,site setting set baseurl,index create,index update,index rebuild,index query,index stats,index refresh,index delete,user create,role list,role detail,permission list,user roles,user add role,user remove role,role add permission,role remove permission,role create,role delete,autoroute create,theme list,theme activate,layer create,widget create,menuitem create,menu create,recipes harvest,recipes execute,recipes result,package create,package install,package uninstall,page create,blog widget create recentblogposts,blog widget create blogarchives,blog create,blog import,blog build archive,feature list,feature enable,feature disable,tags widget create tagcloud.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: even orchard documentation in this link : http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/ , say this command "codegen theme MyFirstTheme/BasedOn:TheThemeMachine" . but this not work !!!

Comment: That's because you haven't enabled Orchard.CodeGeneration. Also, you need a space before that slash.

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy - it is enabeld. and insert space . but show error again

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy - i need full tutorial for orchard cms Version 1.10.3 (emergency) . can you help me? for example add bootstrap to orchard . now add bootstrap,but result not correct !!! tutorials for orchard is for last versions . please help me . thanks

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

The documentation at http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/ should be 99% applicable to 1.10.3.

Comment: So codegen appears nowhere in that long list of available commands, showing that you did not in fact enable the feature. Maybe you thought you did, but you got an error that you didn't see? You can do `orchard feature list` to check, or you can go to the features page of the admin. Also, that error message seems to indicate that you didn't include the word "codegen" in your command.